# Prove that there is a real number $C$ such that for all $f\in L^1[0,1]$, $F(f)=C\int^1_0 f(x) \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $F(f)$ be a bounded linear functional on $L^1[0,1]$ such that $F(f)=0$ for all $f$ such that $$\int^1_0 f(x) \, dx=0.$$ Then Prove that there is a real number $C$ such that for all $f\in L^1[0,1]$ $$F(f)=C\int^1_0 f(x) \, dx.$$

I know that I have to use **Riesz Representation theorem** :

Let $E$ be a measurable set, $1 \leq p < \infty$, and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, then for each linear bounded functional $T$ on $L^p(E)$, there is a unique function $g \in L^q(E)$ such that $$T(f)=\int_Ef.g$$

In this problem $p=1$ and $q=\infty$,therefore for each $f \in L^1[0,1]$ there is a unique essentially bounded function $g$ such that $F(f)=\int^1_0f\cdot g$, My problem is that $C$ must work "for all" $f\in L^1[0,1]$...

Any hints/ideas is appreciated.

Comment: for a start, you state riez representation theorem and try to identity for the objects in the theorem with what you have written here. for example what is the appropriate inner product here?

Comment: Maybe prove something more general.  If $V$ is a vector space, and $f,g$ are two linear functionals on $V$ with the same nullspace, then one of them is a constant multiple of the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Riesz Representation Theorem isn't needed.

Let $C=F(1)$, where $1$ means the constant function equal to 1. If $f$ is any function in $L^1$, write $k_f = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$. Then $F(f-k_f) = 0$ by the hypothesis, so $F(f) = F(k_f) = F(k_f 1) = Ck_f$, as required.

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity I was a little confused the first time I read this too, but if we look we can see 
$$
\int_0^1 (f-k_f) \, \mathrm{d} x = k_f - \int_0^1 k_f \, \mathrm{d} x = k_f - k_f \int_0^1 \, \mathrm{d} x = k_f - k_f(1) = 0
$$
I'm not the most versed in this stuff, but I believe this is true given $x$ is the lebesgue measure. Note that $k_f \in \mathbb{R}$. Then what the answerer says follows

Comment: $\int_0^1 (f - k_f) = \int_0^1 f - \int_0^1 k_f = k_f - k_f = 0$. Therefore $F(f - k_f) = 0$.

Comment: oop im an idiot nvm